# Go Get, Git and Dependencies

Tags: git, go, git-submodules

I'm a moderately experienced Go developer and Git user, but there's something that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

Usually my team uses `.gitmodules` for package dependencies, and that has been a successful pattern because it points to an exact commit.  The entire "vendoring problem" has been solved for us in this way.

However, I recently created a project and used `go get` to fetch various packages from GitHub instead of using `git submodule add`.  I finished the project, committed everything to my git repo, but when a teammate cloned out the repo, the source code for the dependencies was missing.

Usually I would say "oh, you forgot to run `git submodule update --init`", but of course they're not submodules.  So...I could tell him to run `go get -u` or something (right?) but that means I'm at the mercy of the dependency's master branch--enter vendoring.

My real question here is: what *actually* happens when I `go get` a package and then commit it to my repository?  It's not committed into my source tree, and it's not a submodule...I can't tell what the heck it is!  What is the precise way that `go get` and Git are behaving and interacting here?

Bonus round: Why would you want this behavior?  Under what circumstances would you want to commit another project into your repo in a way that forces new checkouts to pull the latest version of the source every time?

Comment: As per https://golang.org/doc/code.html#remote - `go get <package-path>` saves packages to `$GOPATH/src/<packagepath>` - that is, a global GOPATH like a global PYTHONPATH. vendoring, of course, solves that issue, and explicitly bundles dependencies (and their versions) with the project.

Comment: You can use go vendoring with submodules. Golang team fixed that in 1.6. Here's their test case as a sample https://github.com/rsc/go-get-issue-12612 `go get` will checkout the repo and all of it's submodules as vendored packages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically `go get` downloads and installs a project. It starts by cloning the repository of the project you want into the GOPATH. So

```
go get github.com/foo/bar
```

would be equal to

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/foo
git clone git@github.com:foo/bar.git
```

which is a repository of its own.

As of go 1.5 the "vendoring problem" has been solved in a very neat and elegant way and as of go 1.6 it's become the standard way (it was only an experinemt in 1.5). This way you only add the (sub) packages (sometimes single files) you really need, to the structure / repository of your project. There are a few tools out there that take care of vendoring, including [`godep`](https://github.com/tools/godep), from which we currently switched to [`govendor`](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor). It has pretty awesome features. One of which is to update the dependency in your project to a given state (commit, tag, etc) but you can still have the package for other projects, you're working on.
Regarding the bonus question... I'm affraid I'm a bit confused and affraid I don't understand the question in it completely, I'd love to answer it though.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps my question was confusing overall; in any case, you answered half of it. The rest of the question would be how Git handles it when you commit such a repo into an umbrella repo, versus a submodule. Although now that I understand it's just a `clone`, I can probably find the answer written up somewhere.

Comment: The bonus question is basically "why would a tool for fetching dependencies not commit (or allow you to commit) the dependency in a way that allowed for reproducible builds?"

Comment: As I said `godep` is the tool for dependencies, `go get` isn't. Also, I'm not really sure at the moment one can just commit one repo into another... Each of them has a `.git` directory of its own...

Comment: "Basically go get does nothing more than cloning the repository of the project you want" that's wrong. `go get` will clone the project and all of it's dependencies and install all of them. So the bonus question applies and there's no good answer to it - that's probably how Google manages their code base. Master is always good for checkout. Of course that doesn't work outside of Google so external tools for vendoring been created and in Go 1.6 vendoring become official feature. And it's compatible with git submodules

Comment: @Havelock Any idea *what* the behavior is when you do that with Git?  My Google-foo is failing me...maybe it's so obviously a mistake that nobody would think you would ever even try that.

Comment: @creker Given what you listed as the behavior of `go get` I'm beginning to see it makes more sense when viewed like `brew` or `yum` or something: it allows you to obtain a binary for your computer, given the URL of the source code. It just *seems* like it would be good to fetch dependencies from your own project because it puts things in `src` all nicely, but this is just for the sake of its own operation.